# Android Database Search

Tags: android

help please
i want to check user already exist or not.
the value which i am storing in database is only string like username:xyz:address:abc .
I am spliting String by ":"
I want to check only username from the string but not working.Here is my code

1. In DataBase Class

   ```
    public boolean checkEvent(String title) 
     {

       ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

       values=getValues();
       String[] arrBMInfo;
       int j=0;
       String items[]=title.split(":");
   for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++)
   {
       arrBMInfo=values.get(i).split(":");
       if(arrBMInfo[0]==items[0]&&arrBMInfo[1]==items[1])
       {
           Log.d("Title",arrBMInfo[0]+items[0]+"   "+arrBMInfo[1]+items[1]);
                    j=1;
       }
       if(j=1)
           {
                return true;
                j=0;
           }
              else
                return false;
   ```

   }
2. getValues Method in DataBase Class

   ```
   public ArrayList<String> getValues() 
   {

       ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
       String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NAME };
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,
               null, null, null, null);

       if (cursor .moveToFirst()) 
       {

         while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) 
         {
             String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                     .getColumnIndex(DataBase.KEY_NAME));
             values.add(name);
             cursor.moveToNext();
         }
       } 

       cursor.close();
       db.close();
       return values;
   }
   ```
3. In Activity

   ```
   if(helper.checkEvent(UserName + ":" + Address )==true)

   {

           AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,R.style.AlertDialogCustom));

                           dialog.setTitle("Aler Message");
                           dialog.setMessage("Record Already Exit");
                           dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                           {

                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                               {   
                                   dialog.dismiss();   
                               }
                           });

                           dialog.show();
   ```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: mean that AlertDialog should appear but it does not

Comment: my Question is answered by #karakuri  and #karakuri  understand what m i asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.equals()` when comparing Strings, not `==`.

```
if(arrBMInfo[0].equals(items[0]) && arrBMInfo[1].equals(items[1])) {
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Whoever down-voted this, please explain why. The OP says this answered his question...

Comment: yes it solved my problem #karakuri